# Return error response if assertion fails in SoapUI

Tags: soap, groovy, soapui, soap-client

I would like to return a custom error message if an assertion fails in `SoapUI`.

I have written assertions. I always get OK response even though the assertion fails.

I tried below script:

```
def assertionList = []

def idNotNull = (id!=null) ? "(id is not null" : assertionList.add("(id is null")

if(!assertionList.isEmpty())
{
    return "exceptionResponse"
}
assert assertionList.isEmpty() : assertionList.toString()
```

But this will return before assert is executed. Hence assertion is passed though it should fail.

Is there a way that I can achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

It is because the script is returning only a message, but not making it failure. More over, `return` should not be used here. Since there is `return`, the `assertion` statement in your code never reached.

Here is what you need to do:

There are two options you can choose as given below in the script

1. Using If - if condition fails, then show Error
2. Using assertion - show the error message on assertion failure

Here is the complete groovy script below, note that `id` property is not found in the script you provided, so added to avoid property missing error.

```groovy
def assertionList = []
def id 
def idNotNull = (id!=null) ? "(id is not null" : assertionList.add("(id is null")
/**
 * You may use one of the below two options
 */
//Option 1 : Using If condition fails, then Error
//not required to use isEmpty() like you did or null, by default it will check 
if(assertionList){
    throw new Error(assertionList.toString())    
}
//Option 2:Using assertion
assert 0 == assertionList.size() : assertionList.toString()
```